# remove ion refresher blue background

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to override the `ionRefresher` directive so that when it is pulled down, It should not show any loading signs.

Is that possible to do?

I tried doing this:

```
.directive('ionRefresher', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div></div>'

  };
})
```

I have set it up like this:

```
<ion-refresher
    pulling-text=""
    refreshing-text=""
    refreshing-icon=""
    pulling-icon=""
    on-refresh="changeSlide()">
</ion-refresher>
```

But I still get background light blue color on pull down. I do not want that either. Can I change that?

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ionRefresher, ionRefresher (module: starter.controllers)] asking for template on: <div class="scroll-refresher invisible" collection-repeat-ignore="" pulling-text="" refreshing-text="" refreshing-icon="" pulling-icon="" on-refresh="changeSlide()">
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$compile/multidir?p0=ionRefresher&p1=&p2=ionRefresher&p3=%20(module%3A<ion-nav-view name="menuContent" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios">tarter.controllers)&p4=template&p5=%3Cdiv%class%3D%scroll-refresher%invisible%22%20collection-repeat-ignore%3D%22%22%20pulling-text%3D%22%22%20refreshing-text%3D%22%22%20refreshing-icon%3D%22%22%20pulling-icon%3D%22%22%on-refresh%3D%changeSlide()%22%3E
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8895:12)
    at assertNoDuplicate (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17251:15)
    at applyDirectivesToNode (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16689:11)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16286:15)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16298:15)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16298:15)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16298:15)
    at compile (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16193:15)
    at IonicModule.controller.self.appendViewElement (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:52247:18)
    at Object.IonicModule.factory.ionicViewSwitcher.create.switcher.render (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:50449:41)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:21157ident.$get @ ionic.bundle.js:17936invokeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:17479nodeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:16977compositeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:16368nodeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:16972compositeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:16368nodeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:16972compositeLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:16368publicLinkFn @ ionic.bundle.js:16243IonicModule.controller.self.appendViewElement @ ionic.bundle.js:52259IonicModule.factory.ionicViewSwitcher.create.switcher.render @ ionic.bundle.js:50449IonicModule.factory.ionicViewSwitcher.create.switcher.init @ ionic.bundle.js:50369IonicModule.controller.self.render @ ionic.bundle.js:52115IonicModule.controller.self.register @ ionic.bundle.js:52073updateView @ ionic.bundle.js:57485(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:57462parent.$get.Scope.$broadcast @ ionic.bundle.js:24992$state.transitionTo.$state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition @ ionic.bundle.js:44836processQueue @ ionic.bundle.js:23394(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:23410parent.$get.Scope.$eval @ ionic.bundle.js:24673parent.$get.Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:24484parent.$get.Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:24778done @ ionic.bundle.js:19191completeRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:19363requestLoaded @ ionic.bundle.js:19304
```

Can I please get some pointers on this?

Comment: The issue you are getting is caused by the fact you are defining your own ionRefresher directive, in your own module. If you want to override the existing directive (which I would advise against) you need to do this on the ionic module

Comment: I basically just want to extend it. I want to have everything ion-refresher has minus its template. I don't mind replacing it with a custom directive either or I should say I would rather prefer that if I can get it workng the same way as ion refresher does.

Comment: @Anzeo: how should I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to customize directive, just set `spinner` value `none` to disable both spinner or icon.

```
<ion-refresher
    spinner="none"
    on-refresh="changeSlide()">
</ion-refresher>
```

Comment: But that would not get rid off the blue background?

Comment: I don't know from where your blue background is coming. Just set `spinner` none and avoid any kind of customization and remove that directive you are writing on your own. See this http://play.ionic.io/app/2acaf5a7d302

Comment: How can I change the color of the spinner and the dropdown and the content?

Comment: Are you asking about ionic 1 or ionic 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: Using spinner="" used to trow the following exception :

[image: spinner error on ionic framework when using spinner =""]

When I switched to :

```
<ion-refresher on-refresh="doRefresh(false, true)" ng-if="search.canBeLoaded"  refreshing-icon="">
```

and added the following css rule:

```
ion-infinite-scroll .spinner {
    display: none;
}
```

Both spinner from the infinite load and refresh are not displaying as desired.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

add style.css

.loading-container .loading { background-color: black ; } .spinner svg { stroke: #88C931; fill: #88C931; }

Comment: Please add description on your solution

Comment: add style.css

.loading-container .loading
 {background-color: black ;}

.spinner svg
 { stroke: #88C931; fill: #88C931;}

Comment: Edit your answer with this comment